# Does Mocha support multiple before hook for creating independent http server?

Tags: mocha.js

Here is my project structure:

```
src/
 - demo-1/
   - server.ts
   - server.spec.ts
 - demo-2/
   - server.ts
   - server.spec.ts
```

Each `server.spec.ts` has below setup:

```
import { start } from './server';

let server: http.Server; 
before('start server', (done: Done) => {
  server = start(done);
});

after('stop server', (done: Done) => {
  server.close(done);
});

describe('test suites', () => {
  //...
})
```

Here is my `package.json` `scripts`:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha --timeout=3000 --require=ts-node/register ./src/**/*.spec.ts"
  },
```

When I run `npm test`, it gives me an error:

```
 1) "before all" hook: start server:
     Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::4000
      at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
      at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
      at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1351:14)
      at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
      at Server.listen (net.js:1476:7)
      at Function.listen (node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
      at Object.start (src/constructor-types/server.ts:33:14)
      at Context.before (src/constructor-types/server.spec.ts:12:12)
      at Server.app.listen (src/aliases/server.ts:42:7)
      at emitListeningNT (net.js:1378:10)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:11)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

  2) "after all" hook: stop server:
     Error: Not running
      at Server.close (net.js:1604:12)
      at emitCloseNT (net.js:1655:8)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:11)
      at Immediate._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

I expect each `server.spec.ts` works independently which means start the server and run its test suites one by one in order to avoiding http port conflict. Because these servers have a same http port.

Answer (score 0):

Mocha run test files in parallel. Servers will be created same time into one port. 
The workaround is assigning random port for each file (change `start` function to add dynamic port param)

```js
import { start } from './server';

const PORT = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1);

let server: http.Server; 

before('start server', (done: Done) => {
  // change start function accept port param
  server = start(PORT, done);
});

after('stop server', (done: Done) => {
  server.close(done);
});
```

Another solution is [serial-mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serial-mocha) that support running test synchronous. However the package is old, and I don't know if it still work